# AngularJS prevents forms to be submited

Tags: angularjs, forms

I made a very simple form like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="/assets/libs/angular/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form  method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="asas">
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl', [function(){

            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I haven't experienced this type of problems before, but now when I push the submit button, angular prevents form to be submitted.

I tried to add `novalidate` attribute to form, but till no chance.
Also tried to use `ng-submit` to manually submit the form, but it's not working.

I'm using AngularJS v1.5.8

Comment: Where are you trying to submit it to? What did you try putting in the `ng-submit` function?

Comment: Add an action to your form. But usually, forms in an angular app are not submitted in the traditional, web 1.0, meaning of it. They are submitted by calling a method of the controller, that typically makes an AJAX request.

Comment: @Aron I want to the form in a very simple way. Pushing the submit button and it's not working.

Comment: Right but you need to have a destination in order to submit the form. For example in an action attribute, like this `action="/new"`. Without a destination to submit to the form isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, adding `action` solved the problem. I had no idea angularjs may has a brian.

Comment: I have just added my response as an answer. If it helped please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form needs to have a destination in order to submit the form. For example in an action attribute, like here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="/assets/libs/angular/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form  method="post" action="/form-destination">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="asas">
            <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Without a destination to submit to the form isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a submit function in the controller to tell Angular what actions should be taken. And add a `ng-submit` in the form to make a lien with that function. So when you click the submit button, the function in of `ng-submit` will be called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/assets/libs/angular/angular.js" charset="utf-8">  </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="asas">
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.submit = function(){
                // your submit process
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
```